# use dplyr to display level corresponding to the largest sum of some variable variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not sure how to succinctly search for this or to title the question, so apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

I want to obtain `df_1` from `df_0` using tidyverse tools. For each sector, the column `city` in `df_1` should give me the one with more `jobs` for the given sector. Column `jobs` should display the sum of jobs in a sector, irrespective of city.

```
 df_0 <- data.frame(
      sector = rep(c('S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S2', 'S1'), each =  2),
      city = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'), times = 2),
      jobs = 1:10)


df_1 <- data.frame(
  sector = c('S1', 'S2', 'S3'),
  city = c('B', 'B', 'A'),
  jobs = c(22, 22, 11)
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df_0 %>%
  group_by(sector, city) %>%
  summarize(jobs = sum(jobs)) %>%
  group_by(sector) %>%
  summarize(city = city[which.max(jobs)], jobs = sum(jobs)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   sector city   jobs
#   <chr>  <chr> <int>
# 1 S1     B        22
# 2 S2     B        22
# 3 S3     A        11
```